# Best practice: How to use (repeat) CSS style attributes correctly?

Tags: css, css-selectors

As a CSS newbie I'm wondering if it's recommended by professionals to repeat specific style attributes and their not inherited but default properties for every relevant selector? For example, should I rather use

```
body {background:transparent none no-repeat; border:0 none transparent; margin:0; padding:0;}
img {background:transparent none no-repeat; border:0 none transparent; margin:0; outline:transparent none 0; padding:0;}
div#someID {background:transparent none no-repeat; border:0 none; margin:0 auto; padding:0; text-align:left; width:720px; ...}
```

or

```
body {background:transparent; border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
img {background:transparent; border:0; margin:0; outline:0; padding:0;}
div#someID {background:transparent; border:0; margin:0 auto; padding:0; text-align:left; width:720px; ...}
```

or just what (I think) I really need

```
body {background:transparent; margin:0; padding:0;}
img {border:0; outline:0;}
div#someID {margin:0 auto; width:720px; ...}
```

If it's best practice to go with the first or second one what do you think about defining a class like

```
.foo {background:transparent; border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

and then applying it to every relevant selector:

```
<div id="someID" class="foo">...</div>
```

Yep, now I'm totally confused... so please advise! Thanks!

Comment: You can roll your own CSS reset the way you want it. For example you can use `* { border-width:0; border-color:#f00; border-style:solid; }` and then just define a border-width:1px or something to another class, so you just need to tweak 1 place to change all common border colors. Think about inheritance when you design CSS.

Comment: @ricebowl, thanks! =)

@stagas, I will, for sure! *g* Is there sth. like a 'CSS Inheritance Lookup Table' out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your aim in writing CSS should be the readability and maintainability of your stylesheet. Usually that means writing as few rules as possible, a goal that is helped by using as many shortcuts as possible, and taking advantage of the CSS initial values and the browser stylesheet defaults that are reliable.

(Occasionally you may want to duplicate rules a little because you've got two parts of the page that you want to style similarly by coincidence, and you want to split those styles into different sections of the stylesheet so you can manage the sets of rules in groups.)

Not all browser stylesheet defaults are reliable, which is why people use CSS resets. (Although personally I find most of them much too heavyweight and intrusive. Most modern browsers agree on the important stuff, needing just a few hints here and there to fix particular sore points. The overhead of setting a dozen rules like `margin: 0` on *every* element in the document just seems way over the top.)

A lot of the properties in your example are the initial and/or default-stylesheet values anyway, so you gain nothing by including them. (`border-width: 0` is not technically the initial value, but since `border-style: none` is, you won't notice the difference.) Your rules would be much easier to cope with written minimally:

```
body { margin: 0; }
#someID { width: 720px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

> what do you think about defining a class like

```
.foo {background:transparent; border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Well, it depends what `foo` is. If you have many elements on the page that represent the same thing you should certainly mark them up with a `class` and style them all in the same way.

But if you just want to apply some styles to a load of unrelated elements, you should target them separately (using `,` in the selector). Don't pollute the content markup with style concerns by adding bogus classes like `class="red_thing big_border"`.

However as it stands, with those rules which are the same as the defaults for most elements including the `<div>`, `.foo` would be useless anyway.

Comment: bobince, I see the point but then you simply have to know that regarding your 'minimal version' `{margin:0;}` is important here and `{padding:0;}` is not, right? At least, one has to be clued-in on the attributes' default settings and matters of inheritance...

Comment: +1 - there's an important point here: When you want to style things similarly because they're part of a group, use a class to group them. When you want to style things similarly _by coincidence_, group the style rules in the style sheet.

This way, the groupings in your stylesheet reflects the grouping of your content, which is a big plus for maintainability.

Comment: @ellie: yes, some knowledge is needed of default stylesheets to keep rules to a minimum and sadly this is not well-documented—and what doc there is is often out-of-date. For example, it used to be necessary to include `padding: 0` on `body` for compatibility with Opera, which back around version 6 used to use padding instead of margin to get the default page margins. No-one has used this browser for many years, but still the fix hangs around! If you only need to keep up with the modern browsers and IE6+-Standards-Mode there is much less work to do.

Comment: thanks for your brilliant remarks! '...not well-documented...and often out-of-date' - yes, that's a real shame IMHO! However, I'll do my very best to avoid 'markup pollution'.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very common thing these days to use what is called a "CSS Reset". Basically it's just a heap of CSS you chuck at the top of your declarations which resets all the styles to a common base. The idea is to flatten out any differences between the different browsers' default styles. From there, you can be slightly more sure that you'll get what you want from the CSS. One of the more popular ones is [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: nickf, how do you personally handle this 'issue'? Using a css reset and then applying the not inherited style attributes to every single selector? To flatten out all cross-browser incompatibilities sounds good but does not prevent all these repetitions, right?

Comment: Is the 'Reset Reloaded' stylesheet (http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) not the later 'final' version?

Comment: @ricebowl - the dates on the two show the original link to be later (20080212), but thanks for the heads up.
@ellie - style inheritance is a very powerful aspect of CSS. After a reset, I apply or overwrite only the styles I need for that particular element.

Comment: ok, I'll give the 'Reset Reloaded' a try. And, of course, I'd really like to make use of (cross browser-proof) inheritance... could you maybe provide sth. like an overview of the attributes which support this 'feature'?

Answer (score 1):

Always use:

```
border:0;
```

over:

```
border:0 none transparent;
```

If you think about, if the width of the border is 0 (i.e. none) then what use is it to specify the style and color of the border as no border will even be displayed. (The same applies for the background and other properties aswell)

And also, i would go with

```
.foo {background:transparent; border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Its better to apply CSS styles to all elements with a class of "foo" rather than repeating the same CSS code for "someID", "someID2", "someID3" etc.

It will save on bandwidth (as your CSS file will be smaller) and also means that you have to do less work, which is always a bonus.

Comment: So, it's necessary to apply style attributes like `{background:transparent;}` though the default value is used?

Comment: No, because transparent is the default setting in web browsers there's simply no point in doing so.

Comment: The reason browsers have different 'default' settings is the reason people use CSS resets. It's better to define exactly what you want, not guess what the browser would decide to use.

Comment: Valid point, although i'm fairly certain that no web browser will give an element a default background-color of, let's say, blue instead of transparent. Furthermore, if we didn't rely on browser defaults we would have to set a value for every single CSS property - which is not practical at all.